# Lifting nested object properties one level in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, object, graphql, apollo-client

I am currently working on a project with some large objects from a GraphQL API. I am working in TypeScript, and after setting up Apollo Client to generate Type Annotations for all the GraphQL Queries it is a lot easier to work the data. However, I have come across an issue that I am unsure how to handle in TypeScript.

Because I only do queries for the data I need (duuh it's the point of GraphQL) I often have object structures with "extra" unnecessary levels. In Javascript, I would just lift the object property one level, but in TypeScript, I need a bit of help with best practice???

A brief example:

```
if (data?.featuredImage) {
    data.featuredImage = data?.featuredImage?.node;
  }
```

As always you can get away with almost everything in Javascript, but any tips in TypeScript?
I need to clean up the data somehow - the code will be way too unmaintainable otherwise...

All types are generated automatically, but I can of course extend the type/interfaces and make extra types manually.

[Here is a minimal example at TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehBUAsEsGcAJoDsAuBTATgMwIYGM1EEArAV1hXiwHsN4ATNAW2vgAdSM3rZCBaeFEIB5AEbE0eSnHgB3HAE94LDITzUmbADZoAHsGTps+QvRwocASVSZcBeAG9g8F1TTnOaepaY4A5mgAXI5I1IzBAAr+aABCCgCqGNAA+mzRyVjuKJ7evgHJoYwAvsAloCAoMAiGtiZE8AFImOZe8KJKAILcWlqsAMJa0Gio8AKW8Hg4SKGUeJBTAfCVcAY2xvZRAXGJKWn5mR6quemFhE7JySgKbMM4TEHwAEQAsl7QVuhMjwDczvA4WhQ4D0KGCFCSSD88AAPvAkKQer8XJM2ChoNQkGCUBCobD4Yi-tB6FicUj4LBoAAvNCwEnIXFwhFaMmwaicAiJLR0yEwxkElywDB4ADKaFB5Ox9N5+OZf3u9HeABExThoFpaRKcdKmb8SmAzBY5GqtG1CPIlCo1BptHpRm1SJQAFLkSgoViwSDUWRLSCENgYaiiHRMYDqJAUBjmHDBA1WNZ2QgAXngwAcbkOXh80UCfxcDlOwVzrjzKeLZdcAHILlcbkg7mgK8EXm8PsxHgAaIvllwAoEgpvLaoISqEXtLEEdrvdlFojEDqr1EcTHCo9FISfdstE+cyGRLokbzeuCnUjWPQeL33kqk0w9H8lsoVoTk7oc+wis9nPjBaO9HwUimKr6Xh+Qq8Cgf6bvKSoqmqZ4XnuV7QTgjAWHBjxTuWRSlt2ZRFL8RZgFAu7Dle-qBsGdqWFg8DjBQOAYK6rB4DoUzwKQbCRoa4DXDSeBJKil4BrIUpsZgAYYAAdLRchTEx8CDFglCxuBCAcf8CloAAbmgJoCIRICDAA1oQvqqHIZmEI8pyPPUog4BSkw9BaOBGVKS6xvAACMmk6SajBoDcdAiZUbKUChCo8lMShaQCpBoJJBnEW+rL3MsPLjCJPTsbApAAloSj0KwxmEAhSDwI6OCxbA-HQKiObFkWsaSQc2RHFmizJrGAD8LVZDkHVoL1pwEcWYAAOrzJQshslo9Cmu+poRv6+BovYlndTJWUmgmPokblhAAI6kNA6Aab00jlUwSjkRIUiJUAA)

Comment: It would be nice if your code here were a [mcve] suitable for demonstrating the issue when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9Dgm), so that someone who wants to help can get to work on the answer instead of spending time reproducing the issue in the question.

Comment: Cool jcalz I haven't seen the TyeScript playground before. I will edit the post and make an example and repost. Thanks!

Comment: bad example for at least 2 reasons: 1. different/not matching data types, 2. mutation of [usually] read only `data` props (not only TS problem) ... define some new const of node type

Comment: Hi xadm. I have actually seen this pattern before used by others when cleaning GraphQL data. This is the thing with TypeScript: You start thinking that just because it CAN be done it is not necessarily a good idea. 
Just to be clear: How would you do this? This isn't obvious to me really.  The "data" Object is quite large and I might have to do something like this 10 times on different properties of the object plus some mapping.

Comment: just make an alias/shortcut like `if(!data) return <Loading />; const featuredImage = data?.featuredImage?.node; return <Post image={featuredImage} />;`

Comment: Thanks xadm. I still feel that the complexity of my data would get out of hand this way - I also have some instances where I need to map over parts of the object and modify some data. I posted a solution - not sure this is best practice, but it works. But thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I need to compare parts of my object to another object and have some mapping to do also I still needed a way to lifting object properties. I found a solution that works. I am not sure if this is hacky, but for now it gets the job done:

By using the spread operator and a separate object (originalData) I can get all properties and overwrite the ones I need to lift one level without TypeScript throwing an error. Example:

```
const originalData = { ...page };
  let featuredImage: PageByUri_page_featuredImage_node | null = null;
  let parent: PageByUri_page_parent_node | null = null;
  let children: (PageByUri_page_children_edges_node | null| undefined)[] = [null];

  if (!!originalData?.featuredImage?.node) {
    featuredImage = originalData?.featuredImage?.node;
  } 

  if (!!originalData?.parent?.node) {
    parent = originalData.parent.node;
  } 

  if (!!originalData?.children?.edges) {
    children = originalData.children.edges?.map((node) => node?.node);
  }

  const data = {...originalData, featuredImage, parent, children }
  
  return data;
```

If the properties are null they will stay null and if they exist on the object tree properties are overwritten. If anyone has a better way to clean complex graphQL objects I would love to know!

Comment: `featuredImage = originalData?.featuredImage?.node || null;` - no `if` wrapping required? ... but still see it as artificial (or other place/structural) problem (props drilling? possible pagination props loss - more unnecessary changes if pagination support required?) ... `onCompleted`+local state or `useMemo`/`useEffect` for conversions

Comment: Yeah! I clearly need to rethink some stuff and do some refactoring! What I found most difficult with TypeScript is that I need to rethink quite a bit of code, and how I do things in general!